# Move items from one listbox to anotherc - C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, text, listbox

The program I have written is a register, which when a bar code is a scanned, will go to the database and pull out the persons name and I.D. No. and also list a "Time In:" at which time they scanned in. And then when they scan a second time it will add a part "Time out:" like such:

`Peters, Alastair   (242242)    Time In : 14:50    Time Out : 14:50    Time In : 14:50`

What i am looking for it to do is when i first scan in you will see :

`Peters, Alastair   (242242)    Time In : 14:50`

and then when you scan a second time it will add in the `Time Out :` and then remove the entire line and store it in a second listbox, so it does not show when the person is not in.

And then when the person scans in (the 3rd time) it will re-list the previous line, but with the new `Time In`

Any suggestions or ideas would be very helpful!

Here is my code:

```
    private string CreateNewEntry(string current)
    {
        var indexIn = current.LastIndexOf("Time In : "); // Get the last index of the word "in"
        var indexOut = current.LastIndexOf("Time Out : "); // Get the last index of the word out

        if (indexOut > indexIn)
        {
            return current + "      "+"Time In : "; // if the last "out" comes after the last "in"
        }
        else
        {
            // If the last "in" comes after the last "out"
            return current + "      " +"Time Out : ";
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=imis;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        Object returnValue;

        string txtend = textBox1.Text;

        if (e.KeyChar == 'L')
        {
            DBConnection.Open();
        }
        if (DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length != 6) return;
            {
                cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name from name where id =@Name");
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "")));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = DBConnection;

                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "\t (" + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "") + ")";

                DBConnection.Close();

                bool found = false;

                foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    var entry = item.ToString();
                    if (entry.Contains(returnValue.ToString()))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(CreateNewEntry(entry) + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue + "      " + "Time In : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                }

                textBox1.Clear();

                System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
                foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                SaveFile.Flush();
                SaveFile.Close();

                if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
                else
                {
                    EnableCloseButton();
                }
                Current_Attendance_Label.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd be happy to help. Can you please explain what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: thanks @Giovani.

Theres nothing that "is not" working, I just need advice or help with trying to figure out the above.

When i scan myself "Out" , on the even amount of scans, i want it to move the entire line to another list box to hide it, and add "Time out:", then when i scan back in , on an odd amount of scans, i want it to re-enter me into the first listbox with the added "Time in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the starting bit (e.g., "Peters, Alastair (242242)") is unique and remains constant; in that case, you can use `FindString`. Sample Code:

```
int curIndex = listBox1.FindString("Peters, Alastair (242242)");
string wholePetersRecord = "";
if (curIndex >= 0)
{
    wholePetersRecord = listBox1.Items[curIndex].ToString();
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(curIndex);
}
```

This code will find, store in `wholePetersRecord` and delete the first item starting with "Peters, Alastair (242242)" ("Peters, Alastair (242242) Time In : 14:50 Time Out : 14:50 Time In : 14:50", for instance).